# Do we have a Salesforces global database for all clients that installed my package?

Tags: salesforce

Please help me with this question and please correct me if I misunderstand anything.

I am developing a package, in this package, I created some custom objects. I also have my external Web Service and my external database.

As I imagined, when clients install my package from App Exchange, the custom objects will be added to clients side, so they have their own database. The content of custom objects in each clients will be different. Is it correct or not?

And another question: Do I have some kind of "global Salesforce database" (stored in custom objects) but all clients will see it?

Thank you very much for your time! 
Phu Nguyen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Correct. Each client will have own dataset in their database. Read about Salesforce.com [Multitenant architecture](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Multi_Tenant_Architecture).

2) No. But you can create it on external web-service side.